# Best way to model undirected graphs

Tags: neo4j

Just getting started with neo4j. I have a basic modelling question.

Suppose I was modelling road routes between towns A, B & C. Since relations in neo4j are directed, how should I model the fact that A is connected to B and B is also connected to A? Do I need two outgoing relations on each pair of town nodes?

```
(A)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(B)
(B)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(A)
```

Reason I ask is, if I used just one relationship from (A)->(B), the how would I find the path from (B) to (A) using a query like

```
MATCH (B)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->[A]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post might be helpful http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html

Comment: Have to give it to you. This clears the fog totally.

Answer (score 0):

Let cypher be your schema. If you want to look at your graph as an undirected graph, just omit direction in your queries

```
MATCH (b)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(a)
```

There are many cases like this where you can take a certain view on your graph with cypher. ("How many cycles are there?", "Is my graph dense?" and "How do I count connected components?" could all mean different things depending on what relationship types you are currently considering and declaring in your queries.)